# How to set repeating alarms

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm trying to develop an app that enables me to set repeating alarms at a particular time everyday, for example 3.15pm everyday. So far I've managed to get it to fire a notification at the status bar for the first instance of 3.15pm but it doesn't set off another alarm the following day. Below are some of the code that I have written

Setting the alarm

```
public void setAlert(Long taskId, Calendar when) {
    Intent i = new Intent(mContext, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
    i.putExtra(AlertsDbAdapter.FLD_ROWID, (long)taskId);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
}
```

waking up the device

```
public static void acquireStaticLock(Context context) {
    getLock(context).acquire();
}

synchronized private static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
    if (lockStatic==null) {
        PowerManager mgr=(PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        lockStatic=mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                                                    LOCK_NAME_STATIC);
        lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
    }
    return(lockStatic);
}

public WakeAlertIntentService(String name) {
    super(name);
}

@Override
final protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        doAlertWork(intent);
    }
    finally {
        getLock(this).release();
    }
}
```

Setting of the notification

```
NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AlertDisplay.class); 
        notificationIntent.putExtra(AlertsDbAdapter.FLD_ROWID, rowId); 

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 

        Notification note=new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning, "alert", System.currentTimeMillis());
        note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Test Alert", "alert", pi);
        note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; 
        note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 

        int id = (int)((long)rowId);
        mgr.notify(id, note);
```

the code for broadcastreceiver

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```

private static final String TAG = ComponentInfo.class.getCanonicalName();

```
@Override   
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Received wake up from alarm manager.");

    long rowid = intent.getExtras().getLong(AlertsDbAdapter.FLD_ROWID);

    WakeAlertIntentService.acquireStaticLock(context);

    Intent i = new Intent(context, AlertService.class); 
    i.putExtra(AlertsDbAdapter.FLD_ROWID, rowid);  
    context.startService(i);
}
```

}

Am I missing something somewhere in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a `broadcastreciever` class to get to know when to trigger alarm next time.
refer to this [tutorial: Alarm Notification](http://android.arnodenhond.com/tutorials/alarm-notification)

and aslo
Android's Alarm Manager does not remember alarms when the device reboots.
In order to restore the alarms you need to take these steps:

**1. In the Activity which sets the alarms, also save information about each alarm into a database.**

**2. Create an additional `BroadcastReceiver` which gets called at boot-up to re-install the alarms.**

To know more refer to [API Demo's - Alarm](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/index.html#Alarm)

Comment: Hi Sunny, thanks for your reply. I have a broadcast receiver. But based on the sample in the SDK, i noticed that the setRepeating code uses ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP whereas I was using RTC_WAKEUP. This might be the reason for the runtime error that I'm getting

Comment: still need help with this - tried mAlarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi); and it still does not fire another alarm after 15 minutes

Comment: also tried mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi); and it also does not fire another alarm after 15 minutes

Comment: please download this source code this project explain you how to repeat alarm http://alchemiaandroid.altervista.org/alterpages/files/AlarmManagerTutorial.tar.gz

Comment: can this be an issue: PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT